# EntityTypeConfiguration - Set email as unique

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my project i have a setup where i create a separate implementation of IEntityTypeConfiguration for each of my database models.

Now i want to make sure my user all have unique emails, so for my entity config for users, added this:

```
builder.HasIndex(x => x.Email).IsUnique();
```

I create a migration, verifying that indeed, the email now is unique

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_User_Email",
                table: "User",
                column: "Email",
                unique: true);
```

Awesome, now i want to test it, so i create a small test, trying to add a new user with an email that already exist (i'm using an in-memory db for testing).
I Assert that calling the method responsible for this should throw an DbUpdateException, which it does not.

I am able to see both test user, with the same email, in my memory db.

Have any of you guys encountered this before?

Framework is netstandard 2.0 and EF Core is v-3.1.3.

Comment: Are you able to verify that the migration added the index?

Comment: It may be that in-memory db does not respect the unique fields. You may perhaps test this by setting up one unit test to point to a local or dev DB to see if it is different. Some others have come to an hypothesis that it is due to in-memory behavior differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359713/entity-framework-core-unique-index-testing

Comment: @Markuzy, yes i tested it on a local db, no problem, i get the exception i want, referring to email being unique. The problem is only regarding the in-memory db.

Comment: @schwechel i tried to run an update on my local db, and saw it work as intended, throwing an exception on savechanges.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with in memory db, as Markuzy pointed out.